# Angular/Karma - "Unexpected Request" error when expected and observed request are the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm unit testing a controller's method. My app fires off a few GET requests on app start, and I'm getting unexpected request errors when I run my tests.

Here is the login method of my controller. Note: I'm using angular classy (thus the nonstandard syntax):

```
login: function() {
    var self = this,
        params,
        loginSuccess,
        user;

    if (self.$.user.email === '' || self.$.user.password === '') {

      self.$notification.alert({
        title: "Error",
        message: "Email and password can't be blank!"
      });

    } else {

      params = {
         user: self.$.user,
         position: self.Geolocation.currentPosition
      };

      self.$session.login(params).then(loginSuccess);

    }
};
```

Here is the test:

```
describe("LoginController", function() {
  var scope, $rootScope, createController, $controller,
      $httpBackend, $session, session, $notification;

  var emptyCredentials = {
    email: "bleh",
    password: ""
  };

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myapp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector){

    jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath='base/unit/fixtures';

    $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");

    $httpBackend
      .when('GET', 'http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2/apps/3?app_id=3')
      .respond(200, getJSONFixture('apps.json'));
    $httpBackend
      .when('GET', 'http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2.2/locations?app_id=3')
      .respond(200, getJSONFixture('locations.json'));
    $httpBackend
      .when('GET', 'http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2/users/me?app_id=3')
      .respond(200, getJSONFixture('me.json'));

    $session = $injector.get("$session");

    // mock session so that session.loggedIn doesn't return true
    // on subsequent tests
    session = {
      setUser: function() {
      },
      loggedIn: function() {
        return false;
      },
      authPath: function() {
        return false;
      },
      login: $session.login
    };

    $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
    $controller = $injector.get("$controller");
    $notification = $injector.get("$notification");
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function () {
      return $controller('LoginController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $session: session,
        $notification: $notification
      });
    };

    // spies on $notification.alerts
    spyOn($notification, 'alert');

  }));

  afterEach (function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();

    $httpBackend.resetExpectations();

  });

  it('should show alert on empty login credentials', function() {

    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2/apps/3?app_id=3');
    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2.2/locations?app_id=3');
    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2/users/me?app_id=3');

    var controller = createController();
    scope.user = emptyCredentials;
    scope.login();

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect($notification.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      title: "Error",
      message: "Email and password can't be blank!"
    });

  });
```

When I run karma, I get these errors:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2/apps/3?app_id=3
Expected GET http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2/apps/3?app_id=3
    at $httpBackend (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1178:9)
    at sendReq (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:8315:9)
    at serverRequest (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:8049:16)
    at wrappedCallback (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:11520:81)
    at wrappedCallback (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:11520:81)
    at /Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:11606:26
    at Scope.$eval (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:12632:28)
    at Scope.$digest (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:12444:31)
    at Function.$httpBackend.flush (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1438:16)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/myapp/test/unit/controllers/login_controller.test.js:104:18)
Error: Unexpected request: GET http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2.2/locations?app_id=3
Expected GET http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2/apps/3?app_id=3
    at $httpBackend (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1178:9)
    at sendReq (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:8315:9)
    at serverRequest (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:8049:16)
    at wrappedCallback (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:11520:81)
    at wrappedCallback (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:11520:81)
    at /Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:11606:26
    at Scope.$eval (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:12632:28)
    at Scope.$digest (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular/angular.js:12444:31)
    at Function.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation (/Users/myapp/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1470:16)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/myapp/test/unit/controllers/login_controller.test.js:75:18)
```

FYI Line 104 of login_controller.test.js is `$httpBackend.flush()`. Line 75 of login_controller.test.js is `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()`.

I believe the $httpBackend.when() are called before the app is started (and thus before app start's requests are fired), but maybe that's not true. Curiously enough, the error reports that it found an unexpected request of XXX, and the very next line says it expected a request of the same path! So not sure why that's happening.

Running Angular 1.2.21, Angular Mocks 1.2.21

Can anyone explain to me why I'm seeing this error, and what I can do to properly flush and handle those requests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on:

It turns out a vendor plugin was extending the native String object, redefining a match() method. This was conflicting with how angular-mocks was comparing the expectation to the request, and thus threw the error falsely.

If you happen to experience this issue (where expected request and the observed request are identical), look for plugins or libraries that extend the native String object.

Mootools, for example, does this and would cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that now $http uses promises even for request interceptors and so the verification is happening before $httpBackend gets the request. Try adding $rootScope.$digest(); and you will get "No more request expected".

Refer: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5453

Comment: I added $rootScope.$digest to the beginning of the it() callback: `it('should show alert on empty login credentials', function() { $rootScope.$digest(); ...` -- I still receive an Unexpected Request error: `Error: Unexpected request: GET http://myapp.com:3000/api/v2/apps/3?app_id=3 No more request expected`, which doesn't help me handle those requests. Thoughts on how to have the test properly expect and handle the requests?

Comment: Digest will try to execute all the callbacks which are in queue. So after `$httpBackend.flush()` you have to execute `$rootScope.$digest()` before expectations.

Comment: @VamshiSuram Are you sure $httpBackend.flush(); needs to be followed by a $rootScope.$digest() ? My test works just fine without.

Comment: Its been sometime. I think I was referring to a testing process like this:
. `$httpBackend.flush()`  - backend will respond
. `$rootScope.$digest()` - promises are resolved
. `expect(a).toEqual('something')` - expectations are tested.